# Writing array in another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I wish selecting data from three columns and write in another sheet.

What's wrong with my code?

```js
function values() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheets()[0],
      t = ss.getSheetByName('o'),
      range = sheet.getDataRange(),
      values = range.getValues(),
      x = 2;
  
  for (var r = 1; r < values.length; r++) {
    var row = values[r],
        n1 = row[1],
        n2 = row[5],
        n3 = row[9], 
        array = [n1,n2,n3]
    
    for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
      var u = x + y;
      t.getRange(u, 1).setValue(array[y]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am so sorry to post this. I have seen my mistake. I replaced line code var u = x + y by x = x+1

Answer (score 0):

It's better to write the values to an array and then write the array to the sheet in one call. See also: [here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices)

So to optimize the script you could try

```
function values() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
  sheet = ss.getSheets()[0],
  t = ss.getSheetByName('o'),
  range = sheet.getDataRange(),
  values = range.getValues(),
  x = 2,
  array =[ ];

for (var r = 1; r < values.length; r++) {
var row = values[r],
    n1 = row[1],
    n2 = row[5],
    n3 = row[9];
    array.push([n1,n2,n3]);
}  
t.getRange(2, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```